# duplicating index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function to select columns of a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'abc':[1,2], 'xyz':[3,4], 'def':[5,6]})

def select_columns (df):
  res = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='abc')))]
  res = res[res.columns.drop(list(res.filter(regex='xyz')))]
  return res
```

However, I realized that the return `res` have a new column called `Unnamed: 0` which is, in fact, the old index column, and `res` automatically has another new index column.

How can I let the index column untouched while removing some columns?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning your DataFrame while dropping columns without specifying the index. You can avoid this by simply dropping the columns like this:

```
def select_columns(df):
    res = df.drop(columns=df.filter(regex='abc').columns)
    res = res.drop(columns=res.filter(regex='xyz').columns)
    return res
```

You could also just stick to the variable name `df` in the function, since dropping columns will create a copy of the DataFrame by default. So there is no danger of mutating your "outer" DataFrame. **If** you really want to do it inplace and modify the outer DataFrame, you could do this:

```
def select_columns_inplace(df):
    df.drop(columns=df.filter(regex='abc').columns, inplace=True)
    df.drop(columns=df.filter(regex='xyz').columns, inplace=True)
    return None
```

To drop both columns with `regex` in one line, you can use the `|` (`OR`) operator:

```
def select_columns(df):
    return df.drop(columns=df.filter(regex='abc|xyz').columns)
```

This of course also applies to the inplace operations.